# Add a fixed value column to a table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I am prototyping my pig script to hive. I need to add a status column to the table which is imported from Oracle database.

My pig scripts looks like this:

```
user_data = LOAD 'USER_DATA' USING PigStorage(',') AS (USER_ID:int,MANAGER_ID:int,USER_NAME:int);

user_data_status = FOREACH user_data GENERATE
USER_ID,
MANAGER_ID,
USER_NAME,
'active' AS STATUS;
```

Here I am adding the STATUS column with 'active' value to the user_data table.
How can I add column to an existing table to add column while importing the table via Hive QL??

Comment: Are you trying to load data into Hive table after , Altering the table for adding new 'Status' column.

Comment: I am trying to add the 'status' column while creating table on top of CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, You will have to reload the data as you did in Pig.
For example, If you already have the table user_data with columns `USER_ID:int,MANAGER_ID:int,USER_NAME:int` and you are looking for `USER_ID:int,MANAGER_ID:int,USER_NAME:int, STATUS:active`

You can re-load the table user_data_status by using something like this

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user_data_status SELECT *, 'active' AS STATUS FROM user_data;
```

Though there are options to add columns to the existing table, that would only update the metadata in metastore and the values would be defaulted to NULL.

If I was you, I would rather re-load the complete data rather than looking to update the complete table using UPDATE command after Altering the column structure. Hope this helps !

Comment: That makes sense.. Thanks

Comment: So before running 

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user_data_status SELECT *, 'active' AS STATUS FROM user_data;

I should create the table structure for user_data_status. with status column in it?

Comment: Yes @Yuvi... You will have to create the table first with the status column